# How to get right decimals as output in simple fraction

Tags: python, python-3.x, number-formatting

When I write

```
print("{:.4f}".format(333/106))
```

I get the output

```
3.000
```

but when i try

```
print("{:.4f}".format(3.14159))
```

I get

```
3.1416
```

How can I get the correct decimals for the fraction ?

Comment: It looks like, contrary to your tag, you're using Python 2, where `/` between integers is integer division, so the result is the integer `3`.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using Python 2.x, where division of two integers gets rounded result.
Try to specify at least one number as float, e.g. `print("{:.4f}".format(333.0/106))`
or `print("{:.4f}".format(float(333)/106))`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked just right with the code provided and when switching to Python 3.7 I get the output with more decimals

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
pi = 3.1415926
precision = 4
print( "{:.{}f}".format( pi, precision ) )
```

Check this link for formatting [cheat-sheet](https://mkaz.blog/code/python-string-format-cookbook/)